# Debug ASp.NET MVC with IIS5 in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis-5

I have been trying this for some time but could not figure out yet. Is there a way to choose IIS5 as the web server instead of the default Cassini which comes with Visual Studio 2008?

I have web flow(request, response) from my web site to a 3rd party provider and would like to know what I am getting back from the 3rd party.

Right now the Cassini server cannot be open for the world on internet. I have to publish the code in IIS5 and write the response to file to debug. But it would be nice if I could do it in Visual Studio 2008 directly which will save me lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose IIS in the properties of the web project:

[alt text http://learn.iis.net/Content_Cache/387/Properties-Web.png](http://learn.iis.net/Content_Cache/387/Properties-Web.png)

Comment: Yes I already tried that. I get this error

Unable to create virtual directory. Could not find the server 'http://localhost' on the local machine. Creating virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server

I get same error even if I use the ipaddress. The IIS is configured with ipaddress of the computer

Comment: Is IIS running on the same computer as Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes it is on my local machine, Same computer as Visual Studio  with Windows XP Pro

Comment: Ok the error disappeared, I added Webdev.Webserver to windows firewall exception. But when I click on start debugging I get this error now
"Unable to start debugging on the web server. this project is using a website that is configured to use a specific ip address Specify the machine name in the project url"

Any clue?